# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, basically I need to get the new ID from the most recently insterted row...I have this code and it is not working for me...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cd_photo` (id, album, date) VALUES (NULL, '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['album']) . "', '" . $date . "')";

if (@mysql_query($sql)) {
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pageid = $result['id'];
echo $pageid;
echo header('Location: newimg.php?id=' .$pageid);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: PDO and mysql are separate libraries. Also, `$sql` in your code is a string, and not object.

Comment: One other issue: skip the `id` column unless it's set as the primary key with auto-increment.

Comment: I would suggest re-reading the PDO section of the PHP Manual: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: I wanted to use mysql_insert_id() as that is what I am used to using, however I know it is depreciated and when searching around I found the above solution but it does not work, I would prefer not to use PDO as I am not well versed in it

Comment: The above "solution" has many problems as already listed in these comments. The mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. That means that not only mysql_insert_id() is deprecated but also mysql_query(). If you are looking for a quick fix, and it seems that you have PHP version < 5.5.0, then mysql_insert_id() would do the job. However, if you would like to move to MySQLi or PDO_MySQL that would require you to change the logic of all your queries and use the PDO or mysqli drivers to connect to your database and perform queries as already specified in one of the answers.

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau Did the answer below help you out?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different PHP-MySQL APIs. I suggest you use PDO since mysql_ is phased out. Here is how you'd do it in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=dbhost';
$user = 'dbusername';
$pass = 'dbpass';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `cd_photo` (album, date) VALUES (:album,:date)"
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':album', $album);
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
$stmt->execute();
$pageid = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```